# Python: how to find outliers in a specific column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, outliers

I am trying to remove outliers from a specific column in my dataframe in Python. I found a solution from a few year old post that should work, but searches through the entire dataframe:

`df_final[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df_final)) < 3).all(axis=1)]`

Since my dataframe has different data types, such as dates, I am getting the following error when I run it

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timestamp' and 'Timestamp'`

I feel like the solution to just get the outliers for a single column should be easy, but when I try

`df_final[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df_final['rating'])) < 3).all(axis=1)]`

to get the outliers of only the `rating` column, I get an error

`AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1`

I know (think?) that this problem has to do with the array that is created, but I don't understand it well enough to find a solution. Can anyone better explain it to me?

EDIT: It seems that `df_final[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df_final['rating'])) < 3)]` works. Honestly not sure the reasoning behind it, so I'm still interested if anyone can explain or has a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
np.abs(stats.zscore(df_final['rating'])) < 3
```

This line will return a numpy array, value is a series of True and False. This can be used to do slicing.

For numpy.all, please refer tho the [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html). It is not used for your slicing purpose.